# Can network service account username be retrieved as "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32, network-service

I tried the below code. With Python shell running as network service account.

```
import win32con
import win32security
import win32api
win32api.GetUserNameEx(win32con.NameSamCompatible)

output:<MyComputerName>$
```

I am expecting output as `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` and not `MyComputerName$`.
I also tried to get the username from environment variable, gives me same output.

Comment: How exactly are you running this process, and inspecting output. In a service?

Comment: I have a subversion server and my 'script' would get invoked by its 'hooks.' These hooks run as 'NetworkService'.
To run a shell/cmd prompt I use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec).

Comment: I suspect that the process being run is not under the username that you expect. Why not trust the system to know which user the process runs under. Your question should really be about why the process runs under this user.

Comment: I am running cmd prompt as "Network Service". From task manager it reveals the user name is "Network Service". But win32api.GetUserNameEx(win32con.NameSamCompatible) returns what I have already mentioned. I need to receive proper username from api.

Comment: You need to understand what is happening here rather than just demanding a different API call. Do you think you have found a Windows defect? Or do you think you don't yet understand what you are doing?

Comment: use `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` \ `LsaGetLogonSessionData` and you view that no `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` exist. for example `Username: LOCAL SERVICE
LogonDomain: NT AUTHORITY` and `Username: <MyComputerName>$
LogonDomain: WORKGROUP`
but no what you wait

Comment: @David, if I remember rightly, Windows really does return MyComputer$ as the username for the Network Service and Local System accounts.  That sort of makes sense in context; that *is* the username from the domain's point of view.  It's not a bug, it's a feature, but if you want the local name of the account you have to get it another way.

Comment: You'll need to retrieve your SID from the logon token and convert it to a username.  That's not too difficult in C, but I don't know about Python.

Comment: @Harry I read the question as `<MyComputerName>$` being a placeholder for the name of the asker's computer or user. But it returns that specific value? I see now.

Comment: @David, yeah, it's a placeholder.  If the computer is named `HarryPC` then the Active Directory account is `DOMAIN\HARRYPC$` and that's what GetUserNameEx returns.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So is the answer to get hold of the user SID and compare against the known SID for these special accounts.

Comment: @David, you don't need to do the comparison yourself AFAIK, the usual SID to username functions will work as expected - I think.  GetUserNameEx is presumably looking up the SID associated with the logon's network context rather than the SID from the security token.  Or perhaps the unexpected behaviour is hard-coded into it, I dunno. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it's from the LSA logon session. In a case such as this, if you check the process `_TOKEN` in the kernel debugger, you'll see the `AuthorityName` and `AccountName` of the token's `LogonSession` are the `domain\machine$` name. If you instead want the user SID of the token, it's not hard to get this using PyWin32's [win32security](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32security.html) module to call `OpenProcessToken`, `GetTokenInformation`, and `LookupAccountSid`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it's also interesting to note that each service account is logged on with a separate logon session. The SYSTEM logon session (0x3e7) is special in that its `pDeviceMap` is `NULL`, so it creates DOS devices in the `\Global??` object directory, whereas the logon sessions for "NETWORK SERVICE" (0x3e4) and "LOCAL SERVICE" (0x3e5) each get a local DOS devices directory located under `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\00000000-00003e4` (and ...3e5). These logon-session IDs are also used in the 3 service WindowStation names, e.g. "Service-0x0-3e4$".

Comment: @eryksun, I wonder whether the `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` option to LogonUser results in a similar scenario?  It would make sense for GetUserNameEx to return the "new" credentials rather than the local SID - perhaps that's even why they changed it, and the impact on SYSTEM and Network Service was just a side-effect.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, in this case services.exe calls `LogonUserExExW` with the username "NetworkService" and logon type `LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE`. It's more likely the case that the LSA initializes these well-known system logon sessions like this, including `SYSTEM_LUID` (0x3e7), `LOCALSERVICE_LUID` (0x3e5), and `NETWORKSERVICE_LUID` (0x3e4). I haven't checked, but this may also include `ANONYMOUS_LOGON_LUID` (0x3e6) and `IUSER_LUID` (0x3e3).

Comment: @HarryJohnston, when I grant a test user the right to log on as a service and configure a service to use that account instead of one of the 3 well-known service accounts, the test account gets logged on in a session using its own `AccountName` instead of the machine name.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I just came across misleading article about this on [Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160519-00/?p=93495). This issue has nothing to do with friendly names for the service accounts. `GetUserName` has always returned the name from the logon session associated with a token, not the name based on the user SID from the token. Other than these hard-coded logon sessions, I don't know when this could be an issue -- maybe with custom authentication packages.